# how to display image in javascript before it uploads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

html part

```
 <asp:FileUpload class="fUploadStyle" runat="server" ID="fileupload" multiple="multiple" ClientIDMode="Static"  />
 <input style="width: 100px;" type="submit" runat="server" id="btnPreview" value="File Upload" onclick="filedetails(); return false;" />

<table id="tblUpload" style="margin: 0 auto;" border="1"></table>
```

When they choose the image file and the user clicks the button they will preview with a table of file details and can display the image

This is javascript part

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    filedetails = function () {
        var input = document.getElementById("fileupload");
        var output = document.getElementById("tblupload");

        output.innerHTML = '<tr>';
        output.innerHTML += '<th class="thstyle" style="width: 400px;"><b>file name</b></th><th class="thstyle" style="width: 150px;"><b>preview image</b></th>';

        for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; ++i) {
            output.innerHTML += '<td style="padding: 10px; width: 400px;">' + input.files.item(i).name + '</td>' +
            '<td style="padding: 10px; width: 150px; color: #0d47a1"> Show </td>';
        }
        output.innerHTML += '</tr>';
    }
});
```

How can i display the image? even tif format

[this is the interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjpHK.png)

Comment: tblUpload is the table id created

Comment: I think I can help, but I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. Perhaps it's a language barrier. Could you try rephrasing the question?

Comment: okayy actually i just want to display the image before upload to database ...

Comment: but using the tblUpload ..

Comment: This MDN page might be what you're looking for: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications